# How can I enable users to perform actions that require root permission? Can't I just add them to the "root" group?

Tags: permissions, root, users

I added a user to the root group, but the user is still not able to perform operations that require root's permissions. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root login is disabled on Ubuntu. Adding user to root group will only affect permissions of files what have root group, for example edit some config files without `sudo`. Use `sudo` before a command to run that command as root, or `sudo -i` to get a root shell.

Answer (score 2):

`root` login is disabled on Ubuntu. Adding user to the `root` group will only allow access to files that have `root` group, for example some config files. Being in the `root` group does NOT give any special privs.

To grant a user access to `sudo`, read `man sudoers` and add them to the `sudo` group.

```
adduser <username> sudo
```

The, once the other user logs out&in, or does a `newgrp sudo`, the other user will be able to preface his/her command with `sudo` to run as `root`, e.g. `sudo wc -l /etc/shadow`.

Comment: The command `adduser` as given returns an error message. Perhaps you meant `addgroup` instead? Also, you largely duplicated what LeonidMew already answered; you really need to add more content to your answer to superseded his answer.

Comment: @DougO'Neal What exactly did you type? Did you replace `<username>` with the Name of the User? Did you pass exactly two parameters to `adduser`?

Comment: `adduser <username> sudo` where <username> is the name of an existing user.